# kubuntu 16.04 how to reinstall kde/plasma over the top of lxde

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

lxde was installed on kubuntu 16.04.

removed lxde by sudo apt-get purge lxde

re-installed kde/plasma as follows:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop kde-*
sudo apt-get install -f

however, lxde remnants still take precedence.

Hoping for guidance on how to recitfy the desktop situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you are asking is how to remove lxde components completely. Assuming you installed it by `sudo apt install lxde` (or you chose the lxde metapackage from your ubuntu software center) the packages installed are listed here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lxde (including the recommendations). So to remove all the packages execute this command:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge lxde galculator gpicview leafpad lxappearance lxappearance-dconf lxde-common lxde-core lxde-icon-theme lxinput lxrandr lxsession-edit lxterminal xarchiver openbox lxmusic lxpolkit
```

You must choose the recommendations you want to remove yourself from the link above (like clipit, deluge, evince-gtk and others) because some of them would probably be pre-installed.

Comment: Thank you. LCDR et all removed and kubuntu desktop again reinstalled over the top. Part of the problem is that 16.04 won't boot to a login screen and I need to obtain a console an issue a startx command to enter the desktop. When I do so it still boots to a form of lxde. Somehow I need to convince it to use plasma instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: LCDR should be lxde.

Comment: All lxde elements removed as per the link above. Rebooted to plasma. Thank you.